# need 3 static label as title and many dynamic label in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I place one table view in view controller and I set the delegate and datasoure for that. Then I click on that table view and I went to right side of xcode tool to set DynamicPrototype and set prototype cell = 1.

What I need:

```
 Partner  Toy   Learners  ----> this 3 label should be static in tableview

    10      14     15
    12      12     13
    15      20     12
    24      34     43
    23      43     55
    54      54     54
    54      54     54   

Up to 25 Rows.
```

So I place `3 label` inside that `prototype cell`. And I create `iboutlet` for that. But I got error says. Should not `add iboutlet for repatable cell or row`.

Now I need to bring my design like I said above example. `3 static label` and each title have 25 value differntly. When I scroll the table view only my values should scroll. My `3label` should be in same place `should not scroll`

Please help me to solve to get my table view as I need my example abovee. I am new to iOS.

Only I need like above example under `what I need`.Thanks!

EDIT: all my number values are should come from Json (dummy variable). I create that number label as `lab1` `lab2` `lab3`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make the first row not scroll is not to use a row. You have a `UIViewController` to which you manually added a `UITableView` so you can use the table only to display the dynamic data and create a static `UIView` you will place above the `UITableView`.

To create an outlet for your label you can't use your view controller as it will have many cells, you need to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` (one subclass for each prototype cell) you will assign to your prototype cell and then you can create outlets to this class. In order to use them you will need to cast the cell you get from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` to your class.

Comment: Thanks for you replay. About my title of static i will create one new uiview above table view is ok.. And to create a new class with subclass of `UITableviewcell` is ok. After this what should i do with get my 3 label in one tableview cell. Can you please explain  me in code

Comment: I suggest this two tutorials to learn how table views works http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ The second one will explain how to customise your cell (they design the cell in a XIB file but the process is the same with a storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

simple way is using section header or put a view above table & handle scroll offset